# How to GSON/JSON serialize an Android Cursor?

Tags: android, serialization, cursor, gson

```
import android.database.Cursor;
Cursor myCursor = mContentResolver.query(uri, null,..)
String JSON = new Gson().toJson(myCursor, Cursor.class);
```

My string JSON equals an empty [] because myCursor doesn't get serialized properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   private static JSONArray cur2Json(Cursor cursor) {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070791/android-cursor-to-jsonarray
    JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        final int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject(); 
        int i;// = 0;
        for (  i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {

            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    String getcol = cursor.getColumnName(i),
                           getstr = cursor.getString(i);


                    mLog.error("ColumnName(i):\t " + getcol + "\t: " + getstr);
                    rowObject.put(
                                getcol,
                                getstr 
                                 );

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    mLog.error( e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }//for
        mLog.error("columns i:\t " + i + "\totalColumn:\t " + totalColumn); 
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    return resultSet;
}//cur2Json
```

Comment: This is not `GSON` library! This `org.json`. Quetionee requires `GSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code to convert 1 cursor data to GSON Object directly 
column name will be used as the key 
column value will be used as value

```
    Map hashMap = new HashMap();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        hashMap.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),cursor.getString(i));
    }
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(hashMap));
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to convert multiple Cursor Element You can use a arrayList with Map and then serialise arraylist to String

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Map> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Map hashMap = new HashMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            hashMap.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
        }
        list.add(hashMap);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + gson.toJson(list));
```